# Undeclared directive error with WebStorm and aws-amplify

Tags: webstorm, aws-amplify

I'm using WebStorm for development and working with React Native application. I use GraphQL, however, the IDE is continuously giving multiple errors:

> tried to use an undeclared directive
>
> The field type 'AWSDateTime' is not present when resolving

Any suggestions on configuration options?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: It still seems to bug out occasionally.